# How to add a line break to each XML node?

Tags: c++, xml, c++builder, c++builder-xe

How can I add a line break to each XML child bode so the output looks formatted?

The template file contains `<Faults>` and `</Faults>` tags. Now I want to insert a line break inside this node.

**C++ CODE:**

```cpp
_di_IXMLNode nodeFault = NULL;
IXMLNode *m_pRootNode = FormMain->GetBBReportTXMLDocPtr()->DocumentElement;
...
for(; it_Events != lstEvent.end(); it_Events++){
    nodeFault = m_pRootNode->ChildNodes[EVENT_REPORT].Get(EXmlTagOrder::extoFaults)->AddChild("Fault");
    nodeFault->Attributes[WideString("Entry")] = ((*it_Events).m_sEntry).c_str();
    nodeFault->AddChild("Time")->Text = ((*it_Events).m_sTimeStamp).c_str();
    nodeFault->AddChild("Code")->Text = ((*it_Events).m_sCode).c_str();
}
```

But I am not getting output with line breaks or formatting.

When I open the XML file in Notepad, all nodes are on a single line:

```xml
<Faults><Fault Entry="0"><Time>0</Time><Code>20</Code></Fault><Fault Entry="1"><Time>2</Time><Code>10</Code></Faults>
```

The XML file looks formatted when I open it in Internet Explorer instead:

```xml
<Faults>
  <Fault Entry="0">
    <Time>0</Time>
    <Code>20</Code>
  </Fault>
  <Fault Entry="1">
    <Time>2</Time>
    <Code>10</Code>
  </Fault>
</Faults>
```

How can I add a line break to each node so my final output file looks formatted when I open it in Notepad++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set some formatting options before saving to file.

In your specific case:

```
FormMain->GetBBReportTXMLDocPtr()->Options = 
    FormMain->GetBBReportTXMLDocPtr()->Options << doNodeAutoIndent
```

Comment: Thank you it works for me. I need to add it before Inserting and Loading.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [`FormatXMLData()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLDoc.FormatXMLData) function:

> Formats a string of XML so that it is more readable.
>
> Use `FormatXMLData` to convert a string of XML into a format that represents its structure. `FormatXMLData` changes the input string (`XMLData`) so that each element node appears on its own line, indented appropriately to reflect its nesting in the node hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you Remy Leeau ,   I used Options << doNodeAutoIndent  , It works for me,